# Number of integer distance grid points in a cubic grid

Tags: diophantine-equations

Given an $n$-dimensional integer lattice $\mathbb Z^n$, how does the number of grid points $N(k)$ at integer distance $\leq k$ from a given grid point scale asymptotically? I'm mostly interested in $n = 3$ (I'm a physicist :) ), but having also the results for $n = 2$ and $n\geq 4$ would complete the picture.

EDIT: guided by a comment that has now disappeared, I stumbled upon [this reference](http://math.uga.edu/~lyall/Learning/SumsSquares.pdf) that provides the result $N(k) = c k^{n-1}$ for $n \geq 5$.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want the points that are exactly an integer distance from $0$, say? That that is, $(3,4)$ is allowed, but $(3,3)$ is not?

Comment: Correct, (4,3,0) is allowed, (3,3,0) isn't.

Comment: You can use 'Hardy-Littlewood Asymptotic Formula'. I'm writing my answer now.

Comment: Some details for counting the number of ways distance $k$ can be achieved in dimension $n=2$ (sums of two squares) are given [in this PDF](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Bhaskar.pdf). It is well known that among square-free positive integer, those which are products of primes congruent to 1 mod 4 are sums of two squares.  Every positive integer is the sum of four squares, and all but those congruent to 7 mod 8 are the sums of three squares.

Comment: Hm, let's argue for a physicist with physical approximations ;) The value of $x^2+y^2+z^2+\ldots$ (if it is approximately $R^2$) is a perfect square with probability $\approx\frac1{2R}$, so the growth yould be expected to be $\sim k^{n-1}$ instead of the $k^n$ from user1086219's answer ...

Comment: I wrote the comment which had disappeared now, but I deleted it by my mistake, oops. (I wrote the comment again.) By the way, how did you get $N(k)\sim ck^{n/2}$? I think it should be $ck^{n-1}$. We have to calculate $r_n(1^{2})+r_n(2^{2})+\cdots +r_n([k]^{2})$. According to the reference you found, you can calculate $c(1^{n-2}+2^{n-2}+\cdots +[k]^{n-2})$ instead. Using Euler's Summation Formula, we get $N(k)\sim ck^{n-1}/(n-1)$.

Comment: Oops, you're right (lower-cased $N$ instead of making the substitution $N = n^2$). Have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen - as a physicist I indeed consider your answer as most insightful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'Hardy-Littlewood Asymptotic Formula' but it is very tricky...
Let $r_{k,s}(N)$ denote the number of representations of $N$ as the sum of $s$ positive $k$th powers.
Then we have
$$r_{k,s}(N)=S(N)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{s}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{k}\right)^{-1}N^{(s/k)-1}+O\left(N^{(s/k)-1-\delta}\right)$$
where $S(N)$ is uniformly bounded above and below by positive constants depending only on $k$ and $s$. $\delta$ also depends only on $k$ and $s$.

Now We put $k=2$ and $s=n$. Applying Hardy-Littlewood Asymptotic Formula, we have
$$r_{2,n}(N)=S(N)\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)^{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{-1}N^{(n/2)-1}+O\left(N^{(n/2)-1-\delta}\right)$$
where $S(N)$ is uniformly bounded and $\delta$ depends on $n$. Assume that $c_1<S(N)<c_2$ for positive constant $c_1$, $c_2$.
Now we have to calculate
$$N(k)=\sum_{N<k}r_{2,n}(N^{2}).$$
The result is
$$\sum_{N<k}\left(S(N^{2})\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)^{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{-1}N^{n-2}+O\left(N^{n-2-2\delta}\right)\right).$$
This means you can simply calcute $N(k)$ with the inequality
$$\frac{c_{1}\sqrt{\pi}^{n}\Gamma(n/2)^{-1}}{(n-1)2^{n}}k^{n-1}+O\left(k^{n-1-2\delta}\right)<N(k)<\frac{c_{2}\sqrt{\pi}^{n}\Gamma(n/2)^{-1}}{(n-1)2^{n}}k^{n-1}+O\left(k^{n-1-2\delta}\right).$$
This means
$$C_1<\frac{N(k)}{k^{n-1}}<C_2$$
for some constant $C_1$ and $C_2$ depends on $n$.
Well, I think the result is too complicated to use in physics. Maybe you would not be satisfied with the answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically, it simply goes as the volume of the sphere (or the $n$ hyper-ball for generic dimensions).

For $n = 2$ 
 $N(k) \longrightarrow  \pi k^2 $

For $n = 3$ 
 $N(k) \longrightarrow \frac{4}{3} \pi k^3 $

For $n = 4$ 
 $N(k) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}\pi^2 k^4 $

You can find the generalization for any $n$ here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Note that I'm just stating what happens for $k \rightarrow \infty$. 
The formulas above are neither upper bounds or lower bounds of the real integer value, which oscillates above or below that real number.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear: all points not at 'Pythagorean positions' need to be excluded.

Comment: Ahh ok, apologies. Disregard my answer.